# What is Partial apply for closure#1 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, crash-reports

I am trying to make sense of this crash report but can not make sense, because the function "applySettings()" is not called from init() as is shown in the crash report. What is "partial apply for closure#1" in Swift?

[image]

Here is the desired code for init() function.

```
   public override init()
{
    super.init()
    
    discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera, AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInDualWideCamera,
            AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInTripleCamera,
            AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInUltraWideCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
    
    detectLenses()
    
    checkForDeviceAuthorization()
    
    setZoomParams()
    
    sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in
        self.configureSession()
    }

}
```

Comment: What is CapturePipeline.init?

Comment: It's an init() function in CapturePipeline() class

Comment: What is "partial apply for closure#1"?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code of `CapturePipeline.init()`? There is in that code maybe a closure somewhere. See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093409/understanding-crashlytics-crash-report-partial-apply there is no closure as argument in the method, but inside that code there are method with closures.

Comment: @Larme Added the code in the question.

Comment: self.configuresession, there is closure there. uniwned self vs weak self ?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the function called in crash reports you see. The function called in crash reports is applySettings().

Comment: And what code call `applySettings()`?

Comment: It's another function called "resume()" that calls applySettings(). The function resume() is called explicitly when there are events such as application enters foreground on notification, or the view controller appears, etc.

Comment: Have you found out the reason why "applySettings" is related to "partial apply for closure" in init, even though init has no direct link to "applySettings" function?

Answer (score 13):

@DanielKaplan

> I am looking for an answer to the TITLE (as is the OP), not the cause
> of the stack trace. The answer must explain what "partial apply for
> closure#1" means.

A bit of background (from [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=I1ozCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT152&lpg=PT152&dq=swift%20partial%20apply%20for%20closure&source=bl&ots=ASHmuQ3ZKi&sig=ACfU3U1QitZ-pWOIOWo8-MRC7voi4UoNiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitnJaRpIn1AhUg_7sIHQpfBTkQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=swift%20partial%20apply%20for%20closure&f=false), for more deep [in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)):

[image]

So what's going on with?

```
sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in
    self.configureSession()
}
```

Here we have closure calls function directly, swift compiler recognises this and makes currying, ie. instead of call function of function, unwraps closure and injects into `async` direct call of internal function, like

```
sessionQueue.async(execute: CapturePipeline.configureSession(self))
```

but to join this with source code debug info should preserve information about this simplification, so they mark it as *partial apply for closure#* (where N is just ordered number of existed closures in parent function).

And to fix that crash as said before *the best* is to remove that part from `init` at all and call after creation completed. The worse, but depending on other code might be applicable, is to use `[weak self]`.

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, but I don't understand, mainly the paragraph between the two code examples.

Comment: But, this still doesn't explain why "applySettings" is related to "partial apply for closure" in init, even though init has no direct link to "applySettings" function?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do async stuff in an `init`. We are trying to return the initialized object; that is *all* you should be doing here. Everything else should happen in some subsequent configuration call when `self` completely exists.

Comment: That's a good observation. But is that the main culprit here in crash reports?

Comment: Also, does it make any difference to call a function such as buildSession() from init(). And in buildSession(), we do an async?

Comment: I stand by my answer.

Comment: This is something new I hear so pardon me for my ignorance. Generally I see number of function calls in init(). In those function calls, there could be number of async. Is that a wrong paradigm you mean? Is there any documentation for the same?

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question: What is Partial apply for closure#1 in Swift?

Comment: @DanielKaplan So the new question is, in general, what does "partial apply for closure" mean in a stack trace? (No one can explain the OP's crash, because the OP didn't give enough info. So I'm trying to find out what question _you_ want answered.)

Comment: @matt exactly. I've been googling for a while now, and would also appreciate (but not require) a canonical place to learn this on my own, since there are so many other lines I have questions about. e.g., `partial apply for thunk`, `thunk for...`, `closure #3 in...` I found documentation that explains every column of the stack trace, but I can't find documentation about what these terms mean.

Comment: @matt why we cannot do async stuff in an init? In your answer, I see what we should do in `init`, but I didn't see why.

Answer (score 3):

I'll preface by saying I'm not fully confident in my answer.
But after looking around quite a bit, in Swift stacktrace, when a closure immediately executes, it shows up as something like

```
closure #1 in MyAppTabBarController.initialSetup() + 1028 (MyAppTabBarController.swift:469)
```

When it's something that doesn't immediately return (like a network call), it shows up as a partial apply, like

```
partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in DataRequest.response(queue:responseSerializer:completionHandler:) + 56 (ResponseSerialization.swift:167)
```

I'd love for someone to chime in and say confidently that that's the case, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 1):

I got a `partial apply for closure` resulting from a modulus operation (`%`) on a `nil`. Probably not the actual cause though.

I had this:

```
if myArray.count == 0 {
    return
}
let i = foo % (myArray.count)!
```

Fixed by changing it to:

```
if myArray.count == nil || myArray.count == 0 {
    return
}
let i = foo % (myArray.count)!
```

What helped me see the issue, however, was downloading the dSYM files from TestFlight and uploading them to NewRelic, which showed me the exact line in my own code where the crash happened.

This should be doable in XCode also, but for some reason XCode was not showing me the line number this time.