# Swift initializer call Dispatch Queue async

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Is it wrong to call async from Swift object initializer such as this one

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.SerialQueue")
private let property1:Int?

public override init()
{
    super.init()
    /* Initialize properties */
    setupProperties()
    serialQueue.async { [unowned self] in
       self.nonBlockingSetup()
    }
}
private func setupProperties() {
    self.property1 = 1
}
private func nonBlockingSetup() {
    //Some non-blocking code that shouldn't run on main thread
}
```

Some people say async call is problematic before init returns. Need to know what Swift language says about it.

EDIT: Is there any difference if I modify the code as follows:

```
public override init()
{
    super.init()
    /* Initialize properties */
    setupProperties()
    callNonBlockingCodeAsync()
}

private func callNonBlockingCodeAsync() {
   serialQueue.async { [unowned self] in
       self.nonBlockingSetup()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62820455/1187415 ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not an answer to that question. It came out separately which I didn't get completely. So thought of putting it as a separate question.

Comment: @DeepakSharma No, you can't do that, calling `super.init` before initialising property of calling class is not allowed. There won't be any difference.

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your question, I tried out the simple example.**

[image]

`Errors` are very much self explanatory, in the initialisation process `dispatchQueue` are capturing self reference right before it's actual initialisation.

You are running into the `concurrency problem` where initialisation of object is necessary before using it.

`dispatchQueue` uses closures to provide `DispatchWorkItem` and as you know closures captures values surrounding it's scope.

> **Update**
>
> One work around would be to give default values to your properties but
> I am not sure if that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a constructor should not do any meaningful work.

Having a constructor that executes code delayed (because it's async) will be unexpected for anyone using that class (quite possibly including you in 6 months), and can therefore lead to bugs. In such cases it's usually better to have a separate initialization method, which makes it clear to an api user that there is something more going on.

If you absolutely want to make sure the initialization method is called, I usually make the constructor private and add a class method for construction. Again this signals api users that there is something going on behind the scenes.